# Выполнение php при нажатии button

Tags: php, button

Есть кнопка:

```
<button id = "changelog" name="changeSend" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#main-modal">Edit</button>
```

Она вызывает модальное окно. Нужно чтобы она вызывала окно и передавало в это окно **php** переменную. Как это сделать? Желательно средствами **php**.

Модальное окно:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="main-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Изменение рассылки <? echo $lalka; ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div id = "modal-text" class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li>AJAX-отправка запросов</li>
            <li>Уведомление о результате создания рассылки</li>
            <li>Напоминание при незаполненных полях</li>
            <li>Весь функционал перенесен</li>
            <li>Почищен код, часть переписана.</li>
            <li>Улучшены логи</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нажатие кнопки, полагаю, как-то обрабатывается? Видимо, средствами javascript. Вот тот код и важен.

Comment: Используйте AJAX, и получайте свою переменную. А затем выводите в окно.

Comment: @GinoPane, обработчика нет, это Bootstrap, может он как и обрабатывает, я толком не знаю.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев, 
`$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: {'index':ind},
   success: function(e)
   {
      location.reload();
   }
  });
` так?

Comment: @АнтонБурак в этом случае страница перезагрузиться. У вас такое событие прописано при успешном завершении. А так да. Делаете запрос, создайте отдельно функцию которая будет принимать результат. Скажем function resultDelete(forecastData). И её название пишем после success. В forecastData будет содержаться то, что скрипт delete.php напечатает при выполнении. Это может быть  Json. Пробуйте.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев, 
`$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "delete.php", data: {'index':ind}, success: function(e) { alert('OK'); } });` отправляю так, принимаю так `$index = $_POST['index'];` отправляю из файла **delete.php**, в файл **delete.php**, может поэтому не работает?

Comment: Стоп. Вам выводиться alert? Если нет откройте консоль разработчика и ищите ошибку.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев, alert выводится, но когда пытаюсь вывести $index, то ничего не выводит...